# Kohain First Aliya a Requirement?

Tags: kohen-priest, torah-reading, synagogue

I daven on Shabbos in a minyan where I am the only kohain and most often there is no Levi. I feel uncomfortable receiving a disproportionate amount of aliyas and feel that it takes away from others. While I understand it is quite possible the others do not actually care, still, it doesn't feel right to get 4 out of 10 aliyas each Shabbos. I have therefore made it a habit to frequently walk out before the Torah is taken out.

I recently though learned that the Bais Yosef explains the giving of the first aliya to the kohain is because of "darkei shalom," to avoid machlokes as to who receives the first aliya. This places it in a different light. Is my walking out as it is uncomfortable to receive so many of the aliyas and to allow others to receive an aliya a mistake?

Comment: It's nice that you are thinking of others, but do other people actually care? I wouldn't care if the same people got aliyot every time absent some particular special occasion. Makes things run much smoother.

Comment: Thank you @Double AA for your comment. I understand what you are saying but think that in addition to allowing others to receive an aliya, it is also simply uncomfortable to recieve such a disproportionate amount. (4 out of 10 every Shabbos) It may be others do not actually care, but still, it doesn't feel nice.

Comment: I don't have a source for you, but I'm in the position as well many times, and it seems like simple Derech Eretz to notify the gabbai and leave the room at Mincha after you've already had 2 aliyot that morning- there are people who wait over a month to get an aliyah, and I'm going to take 4 in a day? I agree, it doesn't sit right.

Comment: Here's a simple test I've found- if you leave the room and they come get you and insist you take the aliyah, then it's Derech Eretz to take it. If not, let it go

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's hear it directly from the Talmud:

> **Mishnah**: The following rules were laid down in the interests of peace: A kohen is called up first to read the Torah, and after him a Levite, and then a lay Jew. [Gittin 59a]

> **Gemara**: [Why is a kohen called first?] Rabbi Mattenah said: Because the Torah says: "And Moses wrote this law and gave it to the kohanim, the sons of Levi." [Deut. 31:9] Now we know that the kohanim are the sons of Levi, [so why does the Torah tell us that?] What it means therefore is that the kohanim [are first] and then the Levites...

> Abaye said to Rav Yosef: Is this rule only [rabbinic and only] in the interests of peace [so people would not fight about who gets to read first]? Or does it derive from the Torah?  He answered: It does derive from the Torah, but its purpose is to maintain peace. But the whole Torah is also for the purpose of promoting peace, as it is written: "Her ways are ways of pleasantness and all her paths are peace." [Prov. 3:17]

> No, said Abaye... A kohen might want to defer [to a teacher who is not a kohen and this might be misunderstood] and lead to quarreling…  Abaye further said... If there is no Levite present, then a kohen reads in his place. [An objection was raised.] Is that so? Has not Rabbi Yoḥanan said that one kohen should not read after another kohen, because this might cast suspicion on the [legitimacy of the] first kohen? ...
> [Abaye said:] What I meant to say was that the same kohen [should read in place of the Levite].
> [Gittin 59b]

As for leaving to avoid being called for an aliyah, it is a mitzvah to hear the Torah being read.  So much so that the only musical instrument allowed (other than the Torah-mandated shofar) is the rimonim (bells) on top of the scroll, because their jingle during the processional announces a mitzvah.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. As far as missing kriah, this is not an issue as it is readily heard right outside the door. Are you saying there is no question here and that it is clear I should receive 4 out of 10 aliyas each Shabbos because, as the mishna writes, this is the way it was set up to maintain sholom?

Comment: @TorahKnowledgeSeeker Can't you come back in as soon as they make the bracha?

Comment: @TorahKnowledgeSeeker -- That's how I read the Mishnah.

Comment: @TorahKnowledgeSeeker -- As for whether listening to the Torah "from outside the door" fulfills the mitzvah, I don't know and would guess no.  Can anybody cite sources on that?

Comment: The Shulchan Aruch is quite clear, the Cohen only has to leave the room until the first Oleg finishes the bracha. After that you can head right back in, no need to hide in the hallway

Comment: יהושע -- Reference?